# Alembic migrations - script persistence between two deployments

Tags: python, docker, migration, alembic

I have problem with running automated migrations with alembic library (I use **raw alembic** library).

So this is setup of the application:

- I have scheduler (python script which calculates something and then
  stores it in database)
- and flask REST API (which uses data stored in database by scheduler
  to return adequate response)
- I then deploy the app with script which runs these three commands:

```
alembic revision --autogenereate
alembic upgrade head
python run_scheduler.py
```

After initial deployment, `alembic_version` table is created in `PostgreSQL` database with identifier value under `version_num` column, and migration script (lets call this script `xx.py`) is created in `alembic/versions/`

When I redeploy the app (with running migrations and scheduler): I get the

> " Can't locate revision identified by 'xxxxxxx'

## Why?

**Because there is no `xx.py` script anymore (docker is built from source control repo) and xx is the value under `version_num` column in `alembic_version` table.**

How to approach to and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix of author: delete alembic_version table with code below (inside alembic/env.py script)

```
target_metadata = Base.metadata # for context

sql.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alembic_version', engine)
```